# What is a “Boris bike”?

Tags: regional, uk, london, sharing-scheme

They are black and blue, are not light, however what is one?

Have you had any experience of using one?

Comment: Related: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/167/bike-sharing-services-and-systems Possibly combine this question into that thread?

Comment: Added this to [the main bike-sharing thread](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/167/bike-sharing-services-and-systems/952#952).

Comment: I think it's worth noting the scheme was initiated by the previous mayor, Ken Livingstone. They should be called "Ken bike".

Comment: Today I learned that Boris bikes [attract pigeons](http://www.flickr.com/photos/mctumshie/7033293329/in/photostream/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a bike sharing scheme in London, the "Boris" part comes from the mayor's name.

- [Wikipedia article on Barclays Cycle Hire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barclays_Cycle_Hire)
- There's also a small [Boris Bikes community forum](http://www.borisbikes.co.uk/)

[image]

([Photo credit](http://www.flickr.com/photos/stewdean/4941349972/))

Comment: The Mayor at the time being Boris Johnson