# How can I rent a bike in Paris (France) for a short time?

Tags: regional

Is there a system in Paris that will let me rent a bike to get across town, if so how does it work?

Comment: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/167/bike-sharing-services-and-systems/958#958

Comment: Here's a short ebook about cycling in Paris: http://images.bookdepository.co.uk/assets/images/content/blogs/1310634092/BookDep_ParisCycling_FINAL.PDF (PDF), from: http://www.bookdepository.co.uk/blog/post/tag/A-Tour-de-France-download

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [Vélib](http://www.velib.paris.fr/) I think.

[English explanation of the system.](http://www.velib.paris.fr/content/download/3122/27013/version/3/file/V%C3%A9lib%27+-+English.pdf)

Comment: please can you expand this answer a bit as the website is not in English

Comment: I linked their english explanation.